# PHP Extensions "0" must be loaded

Tags: magento-1.7

[image]

ERROR: PHP Extensions "0" must be loaded.

Answer (score 12):

Google helps a lot :)

This is afaik a SimpleXML bug:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800147/how-to-solve-php-extensions-0-must-be-loaded

> If you are installing Magento version 1.7.0.1, try the following to
>   solve your issue:
>
> Replace in file `app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml` (near 71th
>   string):
>
> ```
> <extensions>
>     <pdo_mysql/>
> </extensions>
>  with this 
>
> <extensions>
>     <pdo_mysql>1</pdo_mysql>
> </extensions>
> ```

Comment: Damn, you move fast these days.

Comment: hmmm,,,,,,, this problem solved

Comment: If this solves your problem, please mark this answer as solution.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a problem with compatibility with the php version you are using.

From the [Magento download page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download) you can find patches for all the different version of Magento so that they will work with php 5.4. These patches include the fix regarding the pdo_mysql section of the install config.xml

Answer (score -1):

Quick fix:
in app/code/core/Mage/Install/Model/Installer/Db.php:64
paste following

```
if($extName == 0) {
   continue;
}
```

after

```
foreach ($extensions as $extName) {
```

Comment: Modifying core files is strongly in conflict with Magento best practices.